# How to create a function to lauch org-capture with a selected template?

Tags: templates, emacs, org-mode

Let's say my capture template is bound to 't':

```
(defun my/captureTemplate ()
(interactive)
(org-capture "r")
```

This won't work as it will show me the whole list of potential templates to choose from.
Thanks!

Comment: Please don't ask the same question in [two places](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/63282/how-to-create-a-function-to-lauch-org-capture-with-a-selected-template)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the doc string of `org-capture` with`C-h f org-capture RET` to see how to call it from lisp:

> (org-capture &optional GOTO KEYS)
>
> ...
>
> ELisp programs can set KEYS to a string associated with a template
> in ‘org-capture-templates’.  In this case, interactive selection
> will be bypassed.

So try

```el
(defun my/captureTemplate ()
   (interactive)
   (org-capture nil "t"))
```

In other words, call it with `nil` as the `GOTO` argument and `"t"` as the `KEYS` argument. I assumed that you meant to use the `t` template as you mentioned at the beginning, although you have `r` in your function and I also added a closing paren to close the `defun`.